# How to make a call by clicking on notification

Tags: android, android-studio

I created a notification and I want to make a call when I click on it but I don't know how to do it, I tried to find an answer but I couldn't.

```
notification.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createNotification(v);
        }
    });


public void createNotification(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);

    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setContentTitle("Make a Call")
            .setContentText("0390000000")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.phone)

            .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
}
```

I have to this also but I don't know how to put them together

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("tel: 0390000000")));
```

The code above only open the dialer, but I want to call that number directly.

Any help is appreciated.

M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));


notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        notificationIntent, 0);
```

also add permission in manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change Intent.ACTION_VIEW to Intent.ACTION_CALL
2. Add a permission in Manifest: android.permission.CALL_PHONE

Comment: I did all that, I added the permission to the manifest but if I change to ACTION_CALL still gives me the permission error. Then If I put the startActivity inside the method, when I click the notification button it shows the dialer straight away without waiting for me to click on the notification. I probably forgot to add Button notification = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNotification);

Comment: 1. Read about runtime permissions